# How to get index of value if exists?

Tags: go, redis

I need to store strings and associate a unique integer to each one. The integer must be as short/small as possible . Is it possible to do that in Redis? Basically I need something like `SADD` but instead to return the number of elements in the set I need it to return the index of the element inserted(newly stored or existing).

Pseudo code:

```
 // if mystring already exists in myset it returns its index
 // otherwise stores it and returns its index.
  index := storeOrReturnIndex(myset, mystring)
```

Comment: How large will the integers be? More than 8-bits long? 16? 128?

Comment: As short as possible, that's why I think they should be incremental. I'm building a kind of short URL service but using smallest possible integer instead the shortest possible string.

Answer (score 0):

Would using a hashmap cover what you are looking for?

```
> HSET hashmap 0 "first string"
(integer) 1
> HSET hashmap 1 "second string"
(integer) 1
> HSET hashmap 2 "third string"
(integer) 1
> HGET hashmap 1
"second string"
> HLEN hashmap
3
```

You can store the last modified index in a key with:

```
> SET last_modified 1
```

Then retrieve it with:

```
> GET last_modified
```

Comment: I believe all this should run in a transaction otherwise I could use stale last_modified data... it's pretty much a classic use case of transactions.

Comment: You can actually store the counter inside the same Hash using some unlikely-to-occur string as a field name (I usually use the empty string for that). This makes it easier to do transactions as they touch a single key (and you have the `HINCRBY` command there too). Note that you don&#39;t have to initialize the keys/fields with 1 as Redis will do it (set to 0) for you. I

Comment: You can use the `MULTI` command to bundle the commands together and make it run as a transaction. https://redis.io/topics/transactions

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Redis [INCR](https://redis.io/commands/incr) command to atomically acquire a new, unique index.

> **Pattern: Counter**
>
> The counter pattern is the most obvious thing you can do with Redis atomic increment operations. The idea is simply send an [INCR](https://redis.io/commands/incr) command to Redis every time an operation occurs. For instance in a web application we may want to know how many page views this user did every day of the year.
> To do so the web application may simply increment a key every time the user performs a page view, creating the key name concatenating the User ID and a string representing the current date.
> This simple pattern can be extended in many ways:

So use INCR to get the next unique, smallest index in an atomic way wherever you want to store a new item (URL). Then you can use [HSET](https://redis.io/commands/hset) to store the index associated with your item, and [HGET](https://redis.io/commands/hget) to get the associated index for an item.